# Vifm: run command on each selected file individually

Tags: command, for, vifm

I want a `for` loop analog for [Vifm](https://vifm.info/).

When I don't select any file, I can type `:!echo %f` and I see the output of `echo` with the current file name as the argument.

When I select several files, `:!echo %f` yields output of `echo` with all selected filenames joined with spaces as the argument.

What if I want to apply any program (e.g. `echo`) to each selected file? So

```
echo file1
echo file2
echo file3
...
```

instead of

```
echo file1 file2 file3
```

What options do I have?

P.S.: I want the Vifm analog of the following Bash code:

```bash
for f in file1 file2 file3; do
  echo $f
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will produce the desired output:

```
:!echo %f | xargs -n 1 echo
```

Of course you could define a command (e.g. `for`) for convenient usage:

```
:com for echo %f | xargs -n 1
```

Then you can just type:

```
:for echo
```

Comment: Please note that I am not an experienced ```vifm``` user. This answer is just what came to my mind when I stumbled across your question. It is very likely that there are better solutions which work without the need to call ```xargs```.

Answer (score 1):

#### Option 1: User-defined command

```
:com loop for f in %f; do %a "$f"; done
```

Put that in `~/.config/vifm/vifmrc` to always have the command set-up.

To apply `ls -l` to each selected file, issue

```
:loop ls -l
```

Two macros were used:

- `%f` The properly quoted selected file names.
- `%a` Arguments. In our example, `ls` and `-l`.

#### Option 2: Map

```
:noremap b :!for f in %f; do  "$f"; done<A-B><A-B><Left>
```

Again, put that in `~/.config/vifm/vifmrc` to always have the map set-up.

When you press <kbd>b</kbd> in normal or visual modes, the for loop will show up in the command-line, and the cursor will conveniently be positioned just between `do` and `"$f"`, so you can just type the command you want and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

The cursor positioning is done by the `<A-B><A-B><Left>` part: In command-line mode, <kbd>Alt+B</kbd> moves the cursor to the beginning of the previous word, and <kbd>Left</kbd> (obviously) one space to the left.

**Note**: Remember to add `&` to background the command if it takes long to run and you don't want Vifm to block while it runs.